# Tag ViewPort com bug em Html 5

Tags: jquery, html, android, html5, viewport

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e quero que ela seja responsiva, mas quando coloquei a *tag* :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width ,initial-scale=1.0 ,minimum-scale=0.5 ,maximum-scale=1.0" utf-8'>
```

Alguns componentes que têm interação, animação feitos em *jquery* e *javascript* pararam de funcionar.

Comment: tenta `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Infelizmente já tentei isso também. eu acho que pode ser algum conflito.

Comment: Posta o código das animações que não funcionam pra que outros possam testar.

Comment: Tente usar uma tag com largura definida para ver se o erro continua, por exemplo: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">`